# Как работает list.Where

Tags: c#, linq, list

Хотел узнать сколько итераций сделает Where.

```
var list = new List<byte>(new byte[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 });
int LinqCnt = 0;
var tmp = list.Where(x =>
{
  LinqCnt++;
  Console.WriteLine(LinqCnt+" ");
  return x > 0;
});
Console.WriteLine(LinqCnt+" ");
```

Результат оказался предсказуемым:

```
0
```

Очевидно, что сработал "оптимизатор" и блок с Where просто не сработал. Ну хорошо, добавим следующий недостижимый код:

```
if (tmp.First() == null)
{
    var i = tmp.Count();
    Console.Write(" (i=" + i + ") ");
}
```

Получим:

```
0 1 2 3
```

Странно, т.е. поиск не производился, но за счет обращения к First что-то туда да попало. Продолжим. Добавим еще доп. проверку которая точно сработает:

```
if (tmp.First() == tmp.Last()) Console.WriteLine("LinqCnt+" ");
```

Результат:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 11
```

Итого мы прошлись по всем 5 элементам, а First и Last так же привели к инкрементированию.

Уважаемые знатоки, подскажите что же происходит?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы не совсем правильно понимаете, как работает LINQ.

Дело в том, что в LINQ реализованы *ленивые вычисления*. Реальный пробег `Where` производится не тогда, когда вы определяете `res`, а в тот момент, когда вы производите перечисление.

Последовательность, которая «приходит» в `Where`, может быть слишком большой, или браться из файла, или генерироваться автоматически, и тем самым быть бесконечной.

Например, такой код:

```
IEnumerable<double> RandomSequence()
{
    var r = new Random();
    while (true)
        yield return r.NextDouble();
}
```

производит бесконечную последовательность действительных чисел.

Поэтому все LINQ-операции лишь *запоминают* как должны быть произведены вычисления, но не производят их до тех пор, пока это реально не потребуется.

---

В вашем первом случае, в `tmp` записан лишь «рецепт», как получить последовательность. чисел, больших 0. Если вы хотите реально *применить* этот рецепт и получить `List<int>` (это называется «материализовать последовательность»), вы можете применить `.ToList()`, или пробежаться циклом `foreach`:

```
var list = new byte[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
int LinqCnt = 0;
var tmp = list.Where(x =>
{
    LinqCnt++;
    Console.WriteLine("In where: " + LinqCnt);
    return x > 0;
});

Console.WriteLine("After where: " + LinqCnt);

foreach (var n in tmp)
    Console.WriteLine("Enumerating: " + n);

Console.WriteLine("After enumeration: " + LinqCnt);
```

Вы увидите, что вычисление очередного члена последовательности происходит *параллельно* с выдачей результатов: числа, выводимые в `Where`-клаузе, [«перемешиваются» в выводимым в цикле текстом](http://ideone.com/IuHRg1):

> After where: 0
>   In where: 1
>   In where: 2
>   In where: 3
>   Enumerating: 1
>   In where: 4
>   In where: 5
>   Enumerating: 1
>   After enumeration: 5

---

Что происходит во втором случае? Опять-таки, в `tmp` записан лишь «рецепт», как получать один за одним члены последовательности. Поскольку вы используете `First`, то вся последовательность не нужна: будет вычислен лишь первый член. Для этого исходная последовательность будет проматываться до тех пор, пока `Where` не выдаст первый член результата, и на этом обработка закончится. Поскольку внутрь `if`'а мы не попадаем, больше ничего не происходит.

---

И наконец, третий случай. У вас вызывается `.First` и `.Last`, для одного и того же «рецепта» `tmp`. Это значит, что рецепт применяется **два** раза: один раз последовательность проматывается, чтобы получить первый элемент (до момента, когда этот самый первый элемент будет выдан), а затем — чтобы получить последний элемент. Давайте немного [модифицируем код](http://ideone.com/TCVy5v):

```
var list = new byte[] { 0, 0, 2, 0, 1 };
int LinqCnt = 0;
var tmp = list.Where(x =>
{
    LinqCnt++;
    Console.WriteLine("In where: " + LinqCnt + ", x = " + x);
    return x > 0;
});

Console.WriteLine("After where: " + LinqCnt);

if (tmp.First() == tmp.Last())
    Console.WriteLine(LinqCnt + " ");

Console.WriteLine("After enumeration: " + LinqCnt);
```

Получаем результат:

> After where: 0
>   In where: 1, x = 0
>   In where: 2, x = 0
>   In where: 3, x = 2
>   In where: 4, x = 0
>   In where: 5, x = 0
>   In where: 6, x = 2
>   In where: 7, x = 0
>   In where: 8, x = 1
>   After enumeration: 8

Для вычисления `First` понадобилось пройти три члена исходной последовательности: 0, 0 и 2. Для получения `Last` — все пять.

---

Кстати, отсутствие «ненужных» вычислений — это не фича оптимизатора. Это документированное поведение ленивых LINQ-последовательностей, которое не зависит от того, включен у вас режим оптимизации в компиляторе или нет.

---

Почему же результаты с LINQ выглядят настолько странно? Дело в том, что LINQ пришло к нам из функционального программирования. Там предпочитаются pure-функции, то есть, функции без побочных эффектов. Для таких функций всё равно, сколько раз и когда вызывать их — результат будет один и тот же. Поэтому с «чистыми» функциями ленивые вычисления не приводят к неожиданностям, т. к. всё равно, выполняются ли вычисления (например, фильтрация в `Where`) «ленивым» или «энергичным» образом.

Ваша функция фильтрации, однако, содержит побочные эффекты: она изменяет внешнюю переменную и выводит текст на консоль. Поэтому поведение `Where` и кажется вам неожиданным.

Рекомендуется использовать в LINQ-выражениях чистые функции, тогда вам не придётся следить за состоянием, и держать в голове, какие из LINQ-функций ленивые, а какие нет. Если же вы пользуетесь функциями с побочными эффектами, то вам придётся запомнить, что функции, возвращающие последовательность (например, `Where`, `Select`, `Distinct`) обычно ленивые, а вот функции, возвращающие конкретный элемент (`First`, `Sum`, `Max`) — энергичные.

Comment: Исчерпывающе. Не посоветуете литературу, чтобы подробнее почитать про механизмы Linq?

Comment: @Ice2burn: например, в [списке литературы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/10105), в секции «Литература по LINQ». Если английский для вас не проблема, я бы ещё посоветовал цикл статей [EduLinq](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/index.html) (Jon Skeet), там освещены серьёзные детали.